# Hudson: Mechanism for performing database updates

Tags: java, build, hudson, build-automation, continuous-deployment

We are planning to automate the build system using Hudson. We are new to Hudson or it would be better to say this way that we are new to build automation process. Our application is on Java platform and the database is on MS SQL. This (automation) milestone is break down into different goals.  The first step which we have is to automate database changes (DDL/DML) and during updating database if anything goes wrong it should be able to roll back the changes and send an e-mail to a group to notify the failure (with reasons). Otherwise, if succeed then allow to move on to the next step which is make the build and deploy with [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/#!/).

I think we should have a centric mechanism on build failure on any instance if a build fail it should be able roll back changes what it would have had done. For instance, if database changes failed as I said it should notified and don't proceed further. And, if database succeed and build making process failed (e.g because of Unit Tests) it should be able to roll-back the database changes. If notification can have failure details (like exception details with person responsible for this) it would be very helpful to diagnose and inquire appropriately. How can (should) I do this?

We are also interested to use [LiquidBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) with Hudson.

I would like to ask for your opinion and suggestions how should I plan this and what should be a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't mix up building and deploying. The database update would be part of your deploy process, not of your build process. Even if using continuous integration this should be kept separate. This means you do your database changes after the project was build and all your JUnit tests were run. If it fails before that it shouldn't perform the changes, so there would be no need for rollback.

As for your actual problem: I don't know any plugin that does what you want to do. In Hudson/Jenkins you always have the possibility to execute a batch/shell script. Write a script that performs your changes. The build should fail if your script exits with an error return code.

For sending notifications on build failure there are various plugins, including E-Mail.